# Exposing java objects to R

Tags: java, r, rserve

I want to use R from Java to do some analysis. I have some heavy data objects in Java that I would like to expose to R for the analysis, but not sure how this is done best. I am experimenting with Rserve and I am just building up dataframes and matrices from java and then fire my analysis, but potentially data will not fit in memory (my java objects are under a caching scheme and data is usually loaded in a lazy manner when accessed). Any ideas / experiences / comments will be greatly appreciated :)

Comment: This may help http://blog.datascienceretreat.com/post/69789735503/r-the-good-parts. Use data.table for managing larger objects. We personally had to switch to hadoop streaming with R for larger data collections.

Comment: I would recommend using `JRI`, if your interested in something specific, ill post it as an answer.